# It seems that Debug.Listeners does not exist in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

It seems that **Debug.Listeners** does not exists in net core2.2

In .net framework, I can use this:

```
        Debug.Assert(true);
        Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
        Debug.WriteLine("Debug");
```

then I can see my debug messages in the console when I debug.
But it can't work in net core, it will give error message like that "Debug does not contain Listeners". I use F12 to search(dotnet core):

```
public static class Debug
{
    public static int IndentSize { get; set; }
    public static bool AutoFlush { get; set; }
    public static int IndentLevel { get; set; }
    public static void Assert(bool condition);
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message);
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message, string detailMessageFormat, params object        public static void Assert(bool condition, string message, string detailMessage);
    public static void Close();
    public static void Fail(string message);
    public static void Fail(string message, string detailMessage);
    public static void Flush();
    public static void Indent();
    public static void Print(string message);
    public static void Print(string format, params object        public static void Unindent();
    public static void Write(string message, string category);
    public static void Write(object value, string category);
    public static void Write(object value);
    public static void Write(string message);
    public static void WriteIf(bool condition, object value);
    public static void WriteIf(bool condition, string message);
    public static void WriteIf(bool condition, string message, string category);
    public static void WriteIf(bool condition, object value, string category);
    public static void WriteLine(object value);
    public static void WriteLine(object value, string category);
    public static void WriteLine(string message);
    public static void WriteLine(string format, params object        public static void WriteLine(string message, string category);
    public static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, object value);
    public static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, object value, string category);
    public static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, string message);
    public static void WriteLineIf(bool condition, string message, string category);
}
```

It is true I can't find it, at least it is not public.
How can I debug my application just like before?

The offical document([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=netcore-2.1)) says that Trace and Debug share the Listeners, but my test result is:

```
        TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out);
        //Debug.Assert(false);    //Assertion Failed
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
        Debug.AutoFlush = true;
        Debug.Indent();
        Trace.WriteLine("Trace");   //write Trace
        Debug.WriteLine("Debug");   //Don't write Debug
        Console.ReadLine();
```

and the example use `Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));`, but the `Debug.Listeners` does not exist.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have no way to solve that problem, but I can debug my application like that:

```
    public static void a()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("always show");
        DebugLog();
    }
    [System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
    static void DebugLog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("debug show");
    }
```

just create a new method and then add `[System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`

Comment: Look at the ILogger interface and various providers

Answer (score 21):

As of .NET Core 3.0, you can use [`Trace.Listeners`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netcore-2.2) instead. It affects `Debug` too and is functionally equivalent.

Comment: The API exists, and it will work with `Trace.WriteLine`, but the listener will not receive messages printed with `Debug.WriteLine`.

Comment: They do in NET6 (and probably earlier, I didn't check).

Answer (score 0):

ConsoleTraceListener works just like System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners in .Net before .Net Core like Pathogen David said.

And then very importantly set the Windows application to a Console Application in the Applications Properties page under General->Output type. This is launching the Console window as well as the default form.

I've added this code to main.cs in Main():

```
...
var myWriter = new ConsoleTraceListener();
Trace.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
...
```

Then

```
// Console Logging
Console.Writeline("Your Text here will then be send to the Console");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the default Trace Listener**

AppSettings:

```
"Debug": {
  "DebugFile": ".\\Debug{Date}.log"
},
```

Code:

```
string debugLocation = (string)configurationRoot.GetSection("Debug").GetValue("".GetType(),"DebugFile");
debugLocation = debugLocation.Replace("{Date}", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
var deft = new DefaultTraceListener();
deft.LogFileName = debugLocation;
deft.IndentLevel = 0;
deft.IndentSize = 4;
Trace.Listeners[0] = deft;
Debug.AutoFlush = true;
Debug.WriteLine("----------- "+DateTime.Now.ToString()+ " Application Starting -----------");
```